# How to install html2text (Python)

Tags: python

I'm trying to install html2text and I've used `sudo pip install html2text` but I get the error `ImportError: No module named 'html2text'`
I'm not sure if i need to install any things before doing the html2text install command. I'm very new to Python. I'm using Python 3.5. (Using Mac)

Comment: Have you checked the version of `pip`? Sometimes `pip` refers to `python 2` if both are installed on the system. Then you can try `pip3`.

Comment: `pip 7.1.2 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)` I'm a real noob with the terminal and everything, only started 3 days ago.

Comment: Path to `expert` starts from `noob`. I am still a noob. I think you can see that  the `pip` belongs to `2.7`. Have you tried using `pip3` instead?

Comment: Generally on Mac you can find `pip3` or `python3` etc in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/`

Comment: I used `sudo pip3 install html2text` and it worked! But how do i use html2text? I'm making a program that reads the website for a word. I want to use html2text like this - `url = input()` `html2text(url)` how can i do that? Or if not possible i could use something like - `content = url.read()` `html2text(content)`?

Comment: Anyway, you answered my question. Although you commented instead of posting an answer. So, what should i do?

Comment: Migrated the comment to answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes `pip` refers to `python 2` if both are installed on the system. You should try `pip3`.
Generally on **Mac** you can find `pip3` or `python3` etc in 
`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/`

Answer (score 2):

you can download source from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html2text , then extract archive

```
tar -xvf html2text-2015.11.4.tar.gz
```

and install with

```
python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download from the [official site](http://alir3z4.github.io/html2text/). There is a `.zip` and `.tar.gz` available, download what you prefer, extract it and check the Readme or something similar to install properly.

I have just try this in python 2 and it worked fine

```
mkdir new_directory
cd new_directory
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install html2text
```

I have firstly created a directory. In this directory I have created a virtual environment using virtualenv (`sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv`). I active the virtual environment typing `source/venv/bin/activate`. When the virtual environment is activated, I just install `html2text`.

This install `html2text` in a virtual environment so you couldn't use it without activate the virtual environment.

For Python 3 you could try with `pip install python3-html2text` or download from [this site](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/python/python3-html2text)

Comment: I downloaded the .zip one and .tar one. The README can't be opened on any of them because it has a .md file extension.

Comment: If you have donwload it and extract it, just `cd` into the directory and `sudo python setup.py install`, if this doesn't work, try with `sudo python setup.py build` first

Comment: I think I already have it installed (Before i posted for help) In my list it was there. Would you think the reason is that i have Python 3? The location of html2text is `Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Comment: of course, it seems you have the lib installed in the python2.7 directory

Comment: try with `pip install python3-html2txt` or `pip install python-html2txt`, https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-html2text

Comment: This is what i got - `Collecting python3-html2txt
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python3-html2txt (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for python3-html2txt`

Comment: Note - Before installing Python 3, I installed Python 2. But then removed it and got Python 3. Maybe thats why? ~ I'm really new to Python and terminal so I don't know much about what i'm doing..